# iOS : Hide bottom UITabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using `UINavigationController` and `UITabbar` [like this](http://mocku.ps/tq871b).

From image you can see diagram, I want to hide tabbarcontroller when I tap from image "6" to image "2", very difficult for me.

I tried

> self.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

but uitabbar still display when it return image "2"

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The diagram (storyboard) is a worry. Do you really mean to do what it says? There's a circle; that can't be right, surely.

Remember, when you use a segue, you are a creating a *new* instance of this view controller. So you are creating 2, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 6, and then another 2 on top of that in a potentially infinite loop of view controllers piling up.

Surely you want to do when you get to 6 is to *unwind* all the way back to 2. You want to remove 6, remove 5, remove 4, remove 3, leaving you back at 2.

Or perhaps you want a *different* instance of 2, to show on top of 6, but then it should be different, not the same one coming back from 6 in a loop. It is fine to have more than one instance of the same view controller in your storyboard, and they can be configured differently.

Answer (score 0):

The UIViewController you are pushing, should have this property set.

Here's an example:

```
MyAppViewController *controller = [[MyAppViewController alloc] init];

controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

you are pushing the viewController, so this using this property is applicable to the viewController that is being pushed on to the navigation stack.

remember: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed works only when the view controller is pushed, and wont work as expected when presented modally

Comment: thank you for quick reply,
i tried LoginVC *login = [[LoginVC alloc] init];
        login.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
but still doesn't work.

Comment: and i tried: login.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; as the same

Comment: when you go from image6 to image 2, are you pushing a new view controller? or are you presenting it modally? I believe it should be set in your segue when you connect it from image 6 to image 2 (I haven't used storyboards until now, so its my guess)

Comment: The bottom bar that property refers to is the optional toolbar that you can display when inside a UINavigation controller, not the tab bar owned by a tab bar controller.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen The TabBarViewController inherits from UIViewController, and the TabBarView takes place of the optional toolbar in the navigationController you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard has a loop, it can't work that way.  I suggest you take the login screen out of the flow and instantiate it in code. So it can be used from anywhere easily.

First disconnect all segues then embed it in a navigation controller.
Give the navigation controller an identifier then use:

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
```

Then present it modally which will cover the bottom bar.

Comment: Can you explain more detail, this is my code demo www.mediafire.com/?5gfd9c5f5a7hsov

Comment: i don't understand, if i disconnect segues, I do not think you can call viewcontroller when you delete all segues